# Understanding derivation of gradient optimisation problem

Tags: reinforcement-learning, policy-gradients

I'm following a tutorial on youtube about reinforcement learning.
They are going through the steps to understand policy gradient optimisation.
In one of the steps he says `(delta policy)/policy == delta log policy`.
How can he make that jump?
I have attached a screenshot from the video and also a link to the video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDVteayWWvU&list=PLMrJAkhIeNNR20Mz-VpzgfQs5zrYi085m&index=48&ab_channel=SteveBrunton

[image]

Comment: @Constantinos gave the answer. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2554749/whats-the-trick-in-log-derivative-trick) is a link with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is called the "log trick". Essentially, from calculus:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\log(f(x))=\frac{1}{f(x)}\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$$
Applying the same principle in higher dimensions and you get the equation you wrote.